# How to use the new image replacement technique by Scott Kellum

Tags: image, replace

I am practicing using various image replacement methods and recently came across a couple articles discussing a new, supposedly more efficient method by Scott Kellum.

[Original website article regarding this new method](http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/)

It seems good and I would like to practice using it, but am not to sure what the html and css for it should be. So in the example below, I have an h1, with the example logo text inside. Then I added a class of .hide-text to my h1 and styled it with CSS. I used a photoshop logo image I made and set that as the background image....the image has a width of 203px and a height of 57px.

**Question 1:**
When I tested my code in the browser, everything seems to be working fine, however is my usage of Mr.Kellum's image replacement technique correct?

**Question 2:**
Should I target the h1 in the css and declare the width and height or is it okay to include the width and height directly in the hide-text class like in my example below?

```
<style>
.hide-text {
    background: url(images/mylogo.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 203;
    height: 57px;
    }
```

```
<body>
<h1 class="hide-text">MyLogo text</h1>
</body>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you community!

Answer (score 0):

I have found [the css image replacement museum](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ImageReplacement/) while searching for the actual trends on image replacement. I met the Scott Kellum method's there. After that I found this question - so I'm not an expert using this technique - and i want to share my opinion about.

#### Implementation copy-pasted from the link above

Simple, as also posted on the question.

```
<h3 class="skm">CSS-Tricks</h3>
```

CSS

```
h3.skm {
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
  background: url(test.png);
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

## Implementation as I would do it

I've read the original article and i think it's better to split the css code for reusability. Maybe we'll replace with images more than a single element.

```
<h1 class="ir">An awesome pretty title</h1>
<h2>Some words here not replaced with images<h2>
<nav>
   <!-- some links replaced with images that also use css sprites -->
   <a class="ir" href="#">home</a>
   <a class="ir" href="#">sweet</a>
   <a class="ir" href="#">home</a>
</nav>
```

Reusing the `ir` class for the image replacement technique, as suggested on the post you linked on the question, keeps things tidy.

```
.ir {
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
  background-image: url('/the-title-replacement.png'');
  width: /*the-image-width*/px;
  height: /*the-image-height*/px;
}
nav a {
  background-image: url('/the-menu-icons-sprite.png');
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
nav a { background-position: 0 0; }
nav a + a { background-position: 0 24px; }
nav a + a + a { background-position: 0 48px; }
```

### Conclusions

The image url & the size must be set for each replaced element. If we are using sprites the background position also comes in play for each element, though the element size is often shared between all the elements.

All of this use cases can benefit from splitting the css code, keeping the stylesheet tidier.

**NOTE**: I've made these thoughts for a pure css implementation. Using a css preprocessor - such as less for example - changes the rules.

**NOTE 2**: Another trending method is the [proposed by the H5BP team](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/css/main.css#L117). I am undecided about which to use.